# How to take the Fourier transform of a Fibonacci chain in a Python script?

Tags: computational-physics, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

This may be an easy question to answer but I am really stuck.

In several topics (especially that of quasicrystals) the Fibonacci chain's Fourier transform and diffraction pattern is mentioned. Despite the chain not being periodic, its diffraction pattern shows sharp peaks (a hallmark of quasicrystals). See for example in Math SE

- [Does the cut-and-project method produce *the* Fibonacci chain?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4473449/284619)

I have gotten as far as generating the "canonical" Fibonacci chain using the classic substitution of starting with "L", and replacing "S" with "L" and "L with "LS" literally using strings, then converting the short space "S" to 1.0 and the long space "L" to $\tau = (1 + \sqrt{5}) / 2 = 2 \cos(36°)$ and taking the cumulative sum to produce atom positions in a 1D chain.

These atoms would then be point scatterers of an incident plane wave, so we can see them as identical point sources of waves in phase and use $x \sin(\theta)$ to assign a relative phase as seen from infinity at an angle $\theta$.

Below is shown the results for a chain after 20 iterations, producing 17,711 intervals, a long/short ratio of 1.6180340557 nearly converged to $\tau$ ~1.6180339887. The diffraction pattern (for an incident wavelength of unity) for the fibonacci atoms (blue) certainly shows many peaks between 0 and 30 degrees, and the red sequence (random pattern with the same "L" to "S" ratio) doesn't. The first 100 atoms for each are shown in the top plot with random on top.

But if I wanted to simply apply `np.fft.fft()` without calculating the physical diffraction pattern, how would I do that exactly?

**Question:** How to take the Fourier transform of a Fibonacci chain in a Python script?

---

[image: diffraction from a Fibonacci chain of atoms]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s = 'L'
for i in range(20):
    wow = []
    for thing in s:
        if thing == 'L':
            wow.append('LS')
        else:
            wow.append('L')
    s = ''.join(wow)
    print('length: ', len(s), ' L/S ratio: ', s.count('L') / s.count('S'))

tau = (1 + 5**0.5) / 2

g = np.array([thing == 'L' for thing in s]).astype(float) * (tau-1) + 1.
g_rand = np.array([thing >= 1 / (1 + tau) for thing in np.random.random(len(s))]).astype(float) * (tau-1) + 1.

x = np.cumsum(g)
x_rand = np.cumsum(g_rand)

theta_deg = np.linspace(0, 30, 3000)
theta = np.radians(theta_deg)

i = np.complex(0, 1)
k = 2 * np.pi

amplitude = np.exp(-i * k * x * np.sin(theta[:, None])).sum(axis=1)
power = np.abs(amplitude)**2

amplitude_rand = np.exp(-i * k * x_rand * np.sin(theta[:, None])).sum(axis=1)
power_rand = np.abs(amplitude_rand)**2

if True:
    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1)
    n = 100
    ax1.plot(x_rand[:n], 0.1 * np.ones_like(x_rand[:n]), '.r')
    ax1.plot(x[:n], np.zeros_like(x[:n]), '.b')
    ax1.set_xlim(-2, n)
    ax2.plot(theta_deg, power_rand, '-r', linewidth=0.6)
    ax2.plot(theta_deg, power, '-b', linewidth=0.6)
    ax2.set_yscale('log')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: @DialFrost "How to take the Fourier transform of a Fibonacci chain in a Python script?"

Comment: Not sure (it may sound stupid and it's highly likely I'm wrong), but can't you just put `np.fft.fft()` around the `theta_deg` and `power`/`power_rand`? It seems all one requires to perform a Fourier transformation is to apply it to the np.array itself

Comment: @DialFrost try it, if it works then you can post it as an answer.

Comment: [This is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZp1c.png), I'm not sure if it's correct, so I won't post it yet

Comment: @DialFrost any further thoughts?

Comment: Sorry I don't think so, sorry :(